# What does 管 mean as in "他管我借钱."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

And how do you translate

> 他管我借钱，但我没借给他

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "他(問/求/向)我借钱，但我没借给他" would make more sense,

'管' has many meanings and it is a shorthand for many terms including  管理(to manage) ,  监管 (to supervise),  管制 (to restrict),  掌管 (to control) and 包管(guarantee) etc..

In '他管我借钱，但我没借给他' the most logical meaning for '管' is 'to manage' which implies 'to count on' or 'to rely on'

> 管 = to manage --> put responsibility on --> **counting on** --> depend/ rely on

So the translation of '他管我借钱，但我没借给他' should be "He was **counting on** me to lend him money, but I didn't lend him any"

other example of 管 as different shorthand:

在這處住我管你一日三餐 = 在這處住我(包)管你一日三餐 (you live here and I'll **guarantee** you three meals a day)

香煙的銷售管得很嚴 = 香煙的銷售(监)管得很嚴 (The sales of cigarettes is **supervised** very strictly)

我管你去死 = 我(哪)管(得)你去死 (I **don't care** if you die)

Answer (score 3):

This can be viewed as a series of semantic extensions.

In the sense of *control*,「管」was extended to mean *to have jurisdiction over*, then further extended to mean *to be concerned about, to bother about*.

> 他管我借錢，但我沒借給他
>
> *He bothered me about borrowing some money, but I didn't lend the money to him.*

Similar examples of「管」used in this sense (taken from Pleco):

- 你管得着嗎？(*What business of this is yours?* i.e. *This is none of your concern.*)
- 去不去隨你，我不管 (*Whether you go or not is up to you; it doesn't bother me.*)

Answer (score 2):

他管我借钱，但我没借给他: *He attempted to borrow some money from me, but I didn't lend him any.*

管 just means 向 in this context. 他管我借钱 implies a 想要 or 尝试， 他尝试(/想要)管我借钱.

Answer (score 1):

I think 管 in this sentence means 'find sb. for ....'

Answer (score 1):

管 here doesn't mean "to be concern about" or "to bother that". 管 is obviously a preposition here because it represents no action. The action is 借. 管 here is a typical Northern dialectal expression. It means 向/从/把, i.e., to/from/as...

Therefore,

他管我借钱 He asks to borrow money **from** me.

他管她叫奶奶 He addresses her **as** grandma

他管人家一顿打 He hit somebody hard (no English prep here).

When using 管 in this meaning, it is more oral Chinese than written Chinese. But you can still use it in writing to make your description vivid.

Comment: This is the correct answer mentioning that 管 is actually a preposition here. Have my +1.

Comment: Supplementary material: http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/17876.html It explains "管" as "把", usually in conjunction with "叫", oral usage.

Answer (score 0):

There are many sayings from different dialects with the same meaning in Chinese, we rarely use this form usually. Generally you may speak 他问我借钱, 他从我这借钱, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://dict.baidu.com/s?wd=%E7%AE%A1&device=pc&from=home).

13.作用跟“向”相近：～他借钱。～我要东西。

他管我借钱，但我没借给他。
He from me (want) borrow money, but I not give him
He wanted to hit me for a loan, but I wasn't having any of it.

Answer (score 0):

他管我借钱，但我没借给他

The 管 here means from. He borrowed money from me, but I did not lend him any.